# How do I make a Sound reset after being played?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, hover

Basically if you hover over the anchor it plays the song and when you take it off it pauses it. I want it to pause and reset instead of just pause.
Heres my html

```
<a onmouseover="document.getElementById('mysound').play()" onmouseout="document.getElementById('mysound').pause()" style="display:block" href="MainPage.html">
    <div id="box">
        <audio id="mysound" src="C:/Programming/My Website/Audio/Stalker.mp3"></audio>
        <p id="text"> Enter The Disco! </p>
    </div>
</a>
```

also i would like to have the javascript in a seperate file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
document.getElementById('mysound').currentTime = 0;
```

You can just add it right into your code:

```
<a onmouseover="document.getElementById('mysound').play()" onmouseout="document.getElementById('mysound').pause(); document.getElementById('mysound').currentTime = 0;" style="display:block" href="MainPage.html">
    <div id="box">
        <audio id="mysound" src="C:/Programming/My Website/Audio/Stalker.mp3"></audio>
        <p id="text"> Enter The Disco! </p>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: It seems like it would but im bit of a noob with js so i dont know how to put all this in a separate file and i cant add that to the onmouseout bit cause it doesnt do anything

Comment: What do you mean by put it in a separate file?  You want to declare a function in a separate file and call it?

Comment: basically so its not all on the anchor tag

Comment: Just make a JavaScript file and put the function in it.  Then, include the file in the full document and call the function when the event occurs.

Comment: i tried this HTML:  '<div onmouseover="play();" onmouseout="StopReset();" id="box">
   <audio id="mysound" src="C:/Programming/My Website/Audio/Stalker.mp3"></audio>
   <p id="text"> Enter The Disco! </p>
  </div>'

Comment: JS 'function play(){
 $('#mysound').play();
}
function StopReset(){
 $('#mysound').pause();
 $('#mysound').currentTime = 0;
};
' didnt work

Comment: play(); and StopReset(); arent defined

Comment: You may want to look into how you are defining those functions in the document.

Comment: i have sorted it kind off the only problem now is it says "cannot call method 'pause' of null" the others work though

Comment: Dosent matter now it was because i was calling the id apparently thanks for your help though, thanks very much

Comment: You're welcome.  Also, if you thought the answer was helpful, you should accept it so that the site and future users know that this question has a working answer.